# AC with Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, failover, rac

I'm thinking of configuring Application Continuity for my 2 node RAC (12c) database where my application is running on Weblogic server. Before I proceed with the setup of AC, I need to clarify/confirm few things regarding AC:

1. AC does not require any changes on my application code. This is one of the reasons i'm going with AC because i'm using thin drivers where I cannot use TAF and I do not want FCF as that requires application code changes making it RAC aware. I believe all that is required is to only create a service for AC on my RAC server.
   1.(a) Does enabling FCF add advantage in addition to AC?

The [link in 29th pages](http://www.aioug.org/OTNYathra15/CHE_Kuassi-Mensah_Planned-Unplanned%20-%20Copy.pdf) says FCF is mandatory -- I need to reconfirm on that.

2. Is it mandatory to use FCF with AC? If yes why? If no, I should be fine I guess.
3. Are there any specific changes I should make in Weblogic server if I'm using AC? My Weblogic server could be a cluster/standalone and i'm using normal data source only.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. No.

For the above 2 points, see the below demos (first one is for RAC, second one for Data Guard):

https://laurent-leturgez.com/2015/06/01/oracle-12c-application-continuity-and-its-resources-usage/
https://bdrouvot.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/12c-application-continuity-with-data-guard-in-action/

3. Yes. For details, see the below:

[Application Continuity](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JDBCA/ds_oracledriver.htm#JDBCA583)

[WebLogic Server 12.1.1 and 10.3.6 Support for Oracle 12c Database (Doc ID 1564509.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1564509.1)

Most importantly, you need to modify your data source to use the `oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl` Driver Class.

Comment: @Balaza Papp edited the question with some more queries